# Open debug perpective automatically for a non-public custom launch type

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I implemented an [Eclipse plugin](https://github.com/everit-org/eosgi-e4-plugin) that implements the *org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes* extension. The configuration of the extension is the following:

```
<!-- Own launch config type for EOSGi dists -->
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes">
  <launchConfigurationType
     delegate="org.everit.osgi.dev.e4.plugin.core.launcher.EOSGILaunchConfigurationDelegate"
     id="org.everit.osgi.dev.e4.plugin.core.launcher.launchConfigurationType"
     modes="run,debug"
     name="%name.eosgiLaunchConfiguration"
     public="false"
     sourcePathComputerId="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceLookup.javaSourcePathComputer"/>
</extension>
```

My issue is that the debug perspective is not opened (and it is not asked to be opened) when one of the threads stop at a breakpoint.

The launchConfigurationType is not public and I always create the ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy on the fly without saving it. That is why I do not specify visual tabs for the launchConfigurationType where I could add the common tab and some info about perspectives.

**Question:** How can I assign the debug perspective to a custom, non-public *launchConfigurationType*? I am also interested how can I make my launch type appear on the *window/preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives* panel so the user could set the default behavior.